# List Customer And Product Without Sale

Tags: sql, union

Need to show the following columns (3) using UNION to return:

- All customers who do not have an invoice
- All products that were not sold

1. Category: Is this related to "customer" or "product"? Print "customer or "product"
2. ID: Customer.id (category="customer") or product.id (category="product")
3. Name: customer.customer_name (category="customer") or product.product_name (category="product")

*Tables:*

*Customer*

- id
- customer_name
- city_id
- customer_address
- contact_person
- email
- phone

*Product*

- id
- sku
- product_name
- product_description
- current_price
- quantity_in_stock

*Invoice*

- id
- invoice_number
- customer_id
- user_account_id
- total_price
- time_issued
- time_due
- time_paid
- time_canceled
- time_refunded

*Invoice_Item*

- id
- invoice_id
- product_id
- quantity
- price
- line_total_price

So far have the following:

```
SELECT 
  category,
  CASE
      WHEN category = 'customer' THEN c.id
      WHEN category = 'product' THEN p.id
  END AS 'id',
  CASE
    WHEN category = 'customer' THEN c.customer_name
    WHEN category = 'product' THEN p.product_name
  END AS 'name'
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
        CASE
          WHEN c.id = c.id THEN 'customer'
          WHEN p.id = p.id THEN 'product'
        END as 'category'
    FROM
        customer as c
    LEFT Join -- Left join to show all customers even those with & without invoices
        invoice as i
    ON c.id = i.customer_id
    AND i.id IS NULL -- Gives me all customers who do not have an invoice
    JOIN invoice_item as ii
    ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
    Join product p
    ON p.id = ii.product_id
  ) tb1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  category,
  CASE
      WHEN category = 'customer' THEN c.id
      WHEN category = 'product' THEN p.id
  END AS 'id',
  CASE
    WHEN category = 'customer' THEN c.customer_name
    WHEN category = 'product' THEN p.product_name
  END AS 'name'
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      CASE
        WHEN c.id = c.id THEN 'customer'
        WHEN p.id = p.id THEN 'product'
      END as 'category'
    FROM
        product as p
    LEFT JOIN -- Left join to show all products even those that sold and not sold
        invoice_item as ii
    ON p.id = ii.product_id
    AND ii.invoice_id IS NULL -- Gives me products that didnt sell
    JOIN invoice as i
    ON ii.invoice_id = i.id
  ) tb2
```

Open to any suggestions as I'm stuck trying to figure out how to show the category as either "product" or "customer". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customer product sale query incorrect result in sql server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62954679/customer-product-sale-query-incorrect-result-in-sql-server-2016)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering your data model and requirements, you should try the below SQLs. You can easily perform `UNION` with both the SQLs.

First SQL returns this list --> All customers who do not have an invoice

```
select 'customer' as category, c.id as id, customer_name as name
     from customer c
     left join invoice i on c.id = i.customer_id
     where i.id is null
```

Second SQL returns this list --> All products that were not sold

```
select 'product' as category, p.id as id, product_name as name
        from product p
        left join invoice_item ii on p.id = ii.product_id
        where ii.id is null;
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, it is older than 6 months but still, answer would be:

```
select 'customer' as category, c.id as id, customer_name as name
from customer c
left join invoice i on c.id = i.customer_id
where i.id is null 

union

select 'product' as category, p.id as id, product_name as name
from product p
left join invoice_item ii on p.id = ii.product_id
where ii.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'customer' as category,id,customer_name FROM customer 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT customer_id FROM invoice) 
UNION 
SELECT 'product' as category,id,product_name FROM product 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT product_id FROM invoice_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual question is all customers details even those without invoices and all products even those which are not sold.

```
SELECT    c.customer_name,
          p.product_name,
          Coalesce((ii.quantity), 0) AS quantity
FROM      customer c
LEFT JOIN invoice i
on        c.id = i.customer_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_item ii
ON        ii.invoice_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN product p
ON        ii.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY  c.customerid,
          p.product_id,
          ii.id
UNION
SELECT 'N/A',
       p.product_name,
       0
FROM   products p 
ORDER BY p.id
```