# Customer product sale query incorrect result in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

My DDL looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(50),
CITY_ID INT,
)

CREATE TABLE product
(
id int, 
sku VARCHAR(50),
product_name varchar(100),
stock_qty int
)

create table Invoice
(
id int,
invoice_number varchar(100),
customer_id int

)

CREATE TABLE Invoice_item
(
id int,
invoice_id int,
product_id int,
quantity decimal(5,2),
price decimal(5,2),
line_total_price decimal(5,2)
)
```

I am trying to get sales details of **all customer and products**
output should return **all customer even customer without invoices and
also all product even those product that were not sold**.
**I need to print customer even not have invoice and even those product
that were not sold
than customer and product as NA and quantity as o**

Code i have written:

```
SELECT ISNULL(c.customer_name,'N/A')AS customer_name,ISNULL(p.product_name,'N/A') AS product_name,
sum(ISNULL(invitm.quantity,'0')) as quantity
FROM customer as c left outer join product as p
on c.id = p.id
left outer join invoice as inv on c.id = inv.id
left outer join invoice_item as invitm on c.id = invitm.id
group by c.customer_name,p.product_name
```

But this is giving incorrect result. am i doing any mistake with join. please share your suggestion

Comment: If you have 100 customers, 100 products and no invoices at all, what kind of result you need to get?

Comment: @Arvo: I need to print customer even not have invoice and even those product 
that were not sold
than customer and product as NA and quantity as 0

Comment: Joining Customer.Id on Product.Id could be a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all customer and product combinations, then I would suggest:

```
select c.customer_name, p.product_name,
       coalesce(sum(ii.quantity), 0) as quantity
from customer c cross join
     product  p left join
     invoice i
     on c.id = i.customer_id left join
     invoice_item ii
     on ii.invoice_id = i.id and ii.product_id = p.id
group by c.customer_name, p.product_name;
```

If you want all customer/product combinations that exist and then extras for the customers and products that don't exist, I would suggest `union all`:

```
select c.customer_name, p.product_name,
       coalesce(sum(ii.quantity), 0) as quantity
from invoice i join
     customer c 
     on c.id = i.customer_id join
     invoice_item ii
     on ii.invoice_id = i.id join
     product p
     on ii.product_id = p.id
group by c.customer_name, p.product_name
union all
select c.customer_name, null, 0
from customer c
where not exists (select 1 from invoice i where i.customer_id = c.id)
union all
select null, p.product_name, 0
from product p
where not exists (select 1 from invoice_item ii where ii.product_id = p.id);
```

Comment: @OMG . . . There was a type.  Both queries are fixed:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5968e71a4d2b34b26bb0bda2873c5809.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this (I have not checked syntax) - all your joins were totally wrong; you need to join on corresponding fields (foreign keys), not on id-s:

```
SELECT ISNULL(c.customer_name,'N/A')AS customer_name,ISNULL(p.product_name,'N/A') AS product_name,
sum(ISNULL(invitm.quantity,'0')) as quantity
FROM customer as c full outer join product as p
on c.product_id = p.id
left outer join invoice as inv on c.id = inv.customer_id
left outer join invoice_item as invitm on invitm.invoice_id = inv.id and invitm.product_id = p.id
group by c.customer_name,p.product_name
```

Comment: but there is no column as 'product_id' in customer table.please help

Comment: Well, sorry :), missed that - you need to use cross join then, like Gordon suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a interview question. Below query might be correct:

```
SELECT    c.customer_name,
          p.product_name,
          Coalesce((ii.quantity), 0) AS quantity
FROM      customer c
LEFT JOIN invoice i
on        c.id = i.customer_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_item ii
ON        ii.invoice_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN product p
ON        ii.product_id = p.id
ORDER BY  c.customerid,
          p.product_id,
          ii.id
UNION
SELECT 'N/A',
       p.product_name,
       0
FROM   products p ORDER p.id
```